# RuntimeError: Conflicting 'product_product_options' models in application 'catalogue'

Tags: django, django-oscar

**Version Info:**
Python 3.4, Django 1.8, Oscar Commerce - VERSION = (1, 2, 1, 'final')

I am trying to customize `Products` in the catalogue app following the [documentation](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_customise_models.html).

Having forked the `catalogue` app, I have defined  `models.py` as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct

class Product(AbstractProduct):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

I have already included the modified catalogue, in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in  `settings.py` as a list,  as suggested for a similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-oscar/nuTP_LhS3p4).

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(
      ['app.gravytrain.catalogue',])
```

Have copied the migration folder from `oscar/apps/catalogue` to my custom app.
However running migration causes the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'product_product_options' models in
application 'catalogue': <class
'gravytrain.catalogue.models.Product_product_options'> and <class
app.gravytrain.catalogue.models.Product_product_options'>.
```

How do I get over this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import some models, you need use get_model function.
For example:

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
Product = get_model('catalogue', 'Product')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I have also included "from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *" in the top of the model. Once I was removed it, that issue fixed.